# How can i create fast report frxMemoView programmatically in Delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe, fastreport

I am trying to create a frxMemoView programmatically inside a title bar. Title bar create in design. below code is one of have tried. this is runing. But it doesn't work.

```
   Memo := TfrxMemoView.Create(FRSigningSheet.FindComponent('ReportTitle1') as TfrxReportTitle);
   Memo.CreateUniqueName();
   Memo.Text := 'Hello FastReport!';
   Memo.Height := 20;
   Memo.Left := 5;
   Memo.Top := 5;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can not see in this code the WIDTH property defined. I recomend you to use Memo.SetBounds to set position and size.

If is not working, then maybe the problem is in the Title Bar creation, becouse i have tried your code with my fix and it's working like a charm.

Cheers.

Comment: That's work. Thank you Rafael.I removed height, left ,top then added Memo.SetBounds(100,100,100,100);

Comment: Perfect!

Thanks to you :)